# How to convert alphabets to capital letter from a list comprising of elements with alphanumeric and special characters in Python?

Tags: python, arraylist

I have a list which has elements containing alphabets, numbers and special characters. I want to convert only alphabets to capital letters as shown below:

```
List=["A34_rtXf $ t", "Artyx&-T7", 567, 543,"Aewr-075rJ"]
```

Expected Output:

```
List=["A34_RTXF $ T", "ARTYX&-T7", 567, 543,"AEWR-075RJ"]
```

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could `loop` through the `list` and if the item is of `type: str`, use the `str.upper()` to capitalize the letters of the item.

One liner code would be for example:

```
[i.upper() if isinstance(i,str) else i for i in List]
```

Output:

```
['A34_RTXF $ T', 'ARTYX&-T7', 567, 543, 'AEWR-075RJ']
```

Explanation of the on liner code is as below:

```
l=[]
for i in List:
    if isinstance(i, str):
        l.append(i.upper())
    else:
        l.append(i)
```

Output:

```
['A34_RTXF $ T', 'ARTYX&-T7', 567, 543, 'AEWR-075RJ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `lambda` function to match what you want - make uppercase only string elements - and then apply it to your list with `map`.

```py
>>> List=["A34_rtXf $ t", "Artyx&-T7", 567, 543,"Aewr-075rJ"]
>>> f = lambda e: e.upper() if isinstance(e, str) else e
>>> list(map(f, List))
['A34_RTXF $ T', 'ARTYX&-T7', 567, 543, 'AEWR-075RJ']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ["A34_rtXf $ t", "Artyx&-T7", 567, 543,"Aewr-075rJ"]
new_words = list()

for word in words:
    if type(word) is str:
        new_word = ""
        for char in word:
            if type(char) is str:
                new_char = char.upper()
                new_word += new_char
            else:
                new_word += char
        new_words.append(new_word)
    else:
        new_words.append(word)
    
print(new_words)
```

Output:

```
['A34_RTXF $ T', 'ARTYX&-T7', 567, 543, 'AEWR-075RJ']
```

Answer (score 0):

U could loop over the list and check if the current element is a string oder integer. If it is a string: add with .upper(). If it is an integer: directly add it to the list.

```
List=["A34_rtXf $ t", "Artyx&-T7", 567, 543,"Aewr-075rJ"]

new_list = []
for element in List:
    if isinstance(element, str):
        new_list.append(element.upper())
        print(element.upper())
    else:
        new_list.append(element)
```

output:

```
print(new_list)
['A34_RTXF $ T', 'ARTYX&-T7', 567, 543, 'AEWR-075RJ']
```